# Slick Slider Swipe Gesture not working in WebChromeClient

Tags: webview, slick.js, webchromeclient

I have a WebView set up through WebChromeClient. In the webpage, I've got a [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) 
Everything works there, except the swipe right or left on the slider. How can I handle the swipe gesture through WebChromeClient?